# TSQL calculating from combined queries

Tags: sql, t-sql

I currently have six queries in which I take the results and use a spreadsheet to calculate two different final percentages. I believe that it can be done in a single query, and without a spreadsheet, but I am not knowledgeable enough in SQL to figure it out. I am hoping for some direction from the amazing SQL Gods here on SO.

We have several locations, and calculate a Past Due % and a Past Due Fallout %, per location, based on the average of two other percentages:

- Past Due Dollars ÷ Projected Dollars = *Past Due Float %*
- Past Due Units ÷ Total Active Units = *Past Due Unit %*
- ( *Past Due Unit %* + *Past Due Dollar %* ) / 2 = **Past Due %**

Fallout uses the same calculations, but looks at what the amounts will be tomorrow.

> **SOLVED:** I spent time learning about sub-queries, and joined them by the STID.  Thanks for all who assisted and helped guide me in the
>   correct direction.

Here is my final code:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
DECLARE @Today date = dbo.getdateparam(92,999);
DECLARE @TodayNum int = DATEPART(dw, @Today);
DECLARE @Saturday date = DATEADD(DAY, (6-@TodayNum)%7, @Today);
DECLARE @PrevSat date = DATEADD(DAY, -7, @Saturday);

Select store.STID As Store,
  Proj.ProjRent As Projected,
  PDRent.PastDueDollars As PDRent,
  UOR.Units As UOR,
  PDUnits.UnitsPD As PDUnits,
  (PDRent.PastDueDollars / Proj.ProjRent) * 100 As FloatPerc,
  (Cast(PDUnits.UnitsPD As Decimal) / Cast(UOR.Units As Decimal)) *
  100 As UnitPerc,
  Cast(Round((((PDRent.PastDueDollars / Proj.ProjRent) * 100) +
  ((Cast(PDUnits.UnitsPD As Decimal(18,4)) / Cast(UOR.Units As Decimal(18,4))) *
  100)) / 2, 2) As Decimal(18,2)) As PDPerc,
  Reds.RedsPD As PDReds,
  Round(Cast(Reds.RedsPD As Float) / Cast(UOR.Units As Float) * 100,
  2) As RedsPerc
From 
 -- Stores
(Select Distinct Stores.STID,
    Stores.StoreName,
    Stores.EMail,
    Stores.ManagersName
  From Stores
  Where Stores.STID Not In (7, 999)) As store

  -- Projected Rent
  Left Join (Select CashProj.STID,
    Sum(CashProj.ProjectedRental) As ProjRent
  From CashProj
  Where CashProj.ProjectionDate Between DateAdd(mm, DateDiff(mm, 0, @Today),
    0) And DateAdd(mm, DateDiff(mm, 0, @Today) + 1, 0)
  Group By CashProj.STID) As Proj On store.STID = Proj.STID

  -- Past Due Float
  Left Join (Select Agreemnt.STID As STID,
    Sum(DateDiff(d, Agreemnt.DueDate, (Case DatePart(dw, @Today)
      When '1' Then DateAdd(DAY, -7, DateAdd(DAY, (6 - DatePart(dw,
      @Today)) % 7, @Today)) When '6' Then @Today
      Else DateAdd(DAY, (6 - DatePart(dw, @Today)) % 7, @Today)
    End)) * Round(Agreemnt.WeeklyRate / 7, 2)) As PastDueDollars,
    DatePart(dw, @Today) As TodayNum,
    DateAdd(DAY, -7, DateAdd(DAY, (6 - DatePart(dw, @Today)) % 7,
    @Today)) As PrevSat,
    DateAdd(DAY, (6 - DatePart(dw, @Today)) % 7, @Today) As Saturday
  From Agreemnt
  Where Agreemnt.AStatID = 1 And Agreemnt.DueDate < (Case DatePart(dw,
      @Today)
      When '1' Then DateAdd(DAY, -7, DateAdd(DAY, (6 - DatePart(dw,
      @Today)) % 7, @Today)) When '6' Then @Today
      Else DateAdd(DAY, (6 - DatePart(dw, @Today)) % 7, @Today)
    End) And Agreemnt.RentToRent = 0
  Group By Agreemnt.STID) As PDRent On store.STID = PDRent.STID

  -- Units On Rent
  Left Join (Select Invntry.STID,
    Cast(Count(Invntry.StockNumber) As Int) As Units
  From Invntry
    Inner Join AgreHist On Invntry.InvID = AgreHist.InvID And
      Invntry.STID = AgreHist.STID
    Inner Join Agreemnt On Agreemnt.STID = AgreHist.STID And
      Agreemnt.AgreeID = AgreHist.AgreeID And Agreemnt.AStatID =
      AgreHist.AStatID
  Where Invntry.InvStatID = 11 And Invntry.DisposalDate Is Null And
    Agreemnt.AStatID = 1
  Group By Invntry.STID) As UOR On store.STID = UOR.STID

  -- Past Due Units
  Left Join (Select Invntry.STID,
    Cast(Count(Invntry.StockNumber) As Int) As UnitsPD
  From Invntry
    Inner Join AgreHist On Invntry.InvID = AgreHist.InvID And
      Invntry.STID = AgreHist.STID
    Inner Join Agreemnt On Agreemnt.STID = AgreHist.STID And
      Agreemnt.AgreeID = AgreHist.AgreeID And AgreHist.AStatID =
      Agreemnt.AStatID
  Where Invntry.InvStatID = 11 And Invntry.DisposalDate Is Null And
    Agreemnt.AStatID = 1 And Agreemnt.DueDate < (Case @TodayNum When '1' Then @PrevSat When '6' Then @Today Else @Saturday End) And Agreemnt.RentToRent = 0
  Group By Invntry.STID) As PDUnits On store.STID = PDUnits.STID

  -- Reds
  Left Join (Select Invntry.STID,
    Count(Invntry.StockNumber) As RedsPD
  From Invntry
    Inner Join AgreHist On Invntry.InvID = AgreHist.InvID And
      Invntry.STID = AgreHist.STID
    Inner Join Agreemnt On Agreemnt.STID = AgreHist.STID And
      Agreemnt.AgreeID = AgreHist.AgreeID And Agreemnt.AStatID =
      AgreHist.AStatID
  Where Invntry.InvStatID = 11 And Invntry.DisposalDate Is Null And
    Agreemnt.AStatID = 1 And Agreemnt.DueDate < DateAdd(day, -15, Case
      Cast(DatePart(dw, @Today) As Int)
      When '1' Then Cast(DateAdd(DAY, -7, DateAdd(DAY, (6 - DatePart(dw,
      @Today)) % 7, @Today)) As Date)
      When '6' Then Cast(@Today As Date)
      Else Cast(DateAdd(DAY, (6 - DatePart(dw, @Today)) % 7, @Today) As
      Date) End) And Agreemnt.RentToRent = 0
  Group By Invntry.STID) As Reds On store.STID = Reds.STID
Order By Store
```

Comment: Without reading all of these details..I Have one simple question for you.  Within all these queries is there any field (column from your table) that relates all of these queries together?  If so, your answer is simple, you join back to all these queries using a derived query.  it looks like your result set says yes there is..so you would do `SELECT .. FROM FirstQuery t1 JOIN ( SELECT .. FROM YourSecondQuery) t2 ON t2.SomeID = t1.SomeID` and you continue from there.

Comment: @JonH All have a common field Agreemnt.STID, EXCEPT for ProjectedDollars, which queries a single table.

Comment: in order to relate tables there needs to be some relationship, if you don't have the relationship how do you expect sql server to give you this query...it cannot because you cannot tell it what you want.  You need to establish how this table  links to the other tables.

Comment: @JonH I can see that combining the queries, but not allowing me to use the results to calculate the end desired numbers.

Comment: so post what you tried when you combined the queries with expected results, this is too much info.

Comment: I thought maybe a temp table? But I don't know enough about SQL to even know where to start....

Comment: Its the same thing with a temp table...temp table is just a way to temporarily store your data, but somehow that data needs to make sense and inserted into a temp table to use.  You need to establish how these columns relate to help you come up with a query.

Comment: @JonH I have added what I have tried to my initial question.

Comment: what version of sql server are you on?

Comment: @dotjoe SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use variables like that and you can't do this in one aggregate query because it's going to create a massive Cartesian product and give you incorrect results.

You could use CTE's or subqueries for each query you have listed and then join them together on the STID and apply your formulas.

example...

```
/* declare all variables here */
DECLARE @dayNum INT;
SET @dayNum = datepart(dw, getdate());

with PastDueDollars as (
    select ... from ... group by STID
), ProjectedDollers as (
    select ... from ... group by STID
), PastDueUnits as (
    select ... from ... group by STID
), preFinal as (

    select
        PastDueDollarRatio = pdd.PastDueDollars / pd.ProjRent,
        PastDueUnitRatio = pdu.UnitsPD / tau.TotalActiveUnits
        /* add the other calculations */
    from
        PastDueDollars pdd
        inner join ProjectedDollers pd on pdd.STID = pd.STID
        inner join PastDueUnits pdu on pdu.STID = pd.STID
        /* join more CTEs */
)

select
    f.*,
    PastDueRatio = (f.PastDueDollarRatio + f.PastDueUnitRatio) / 2
    /* and so on for the other calculations of calculations... */
from
    preFinal f
```

Comment: This somewhat seems like what I may need, but then how would I calculate the final percentages?

Comment: I guess what I don't understand is that if I use a CTE for each query and the join them together on the STID, how do I create variables from the query results, run my calculations, and then output the query results AND the calculated results all together.  I just haven't had that "ah ha" moment yet... :/

Comment: @thelincster you don't need variables..you can do the calculations in the select clause of the final query.

Comment: ok, I guess I don't understand how I can run four queries, calculate two different numbers from the results of those queries and then calculate a final number from the results of those two different numbers.  What am I missing?

Comment: 1. Query A = Result A, Query B = Result B, Query C = Result C, Query D = Result D, Query E = Result E, Query F = Result F   -------
2. Result A / Result B = First Number, Result C / Result D = Second Number.  -----  
3. First Number / Second Number = First Final.  -----  
4. Result E / Result B = Third Number, Result F / Result D = Fourth Number.  -----  
5. Third Number / Fourth Number = Second Final.  -----  
Output: Result A, Result B, Result C, Result D, First Final, Result E, Result F, Second Final

Comment: Add another select on top of it if you don't want to repeat any calculations. Could you update your answer with your progress?

Answer (score 0):

You never set the variables to any real value, the you proceed to select the useless variable in a irrelevant SELECT statement.

in the following line

```
Set @pdD = Sum( Case When a.DueDate < GetDate() Then DateDiff(d,a.DueDate,@runDate) * (a.WeeklyRate/7) )
```

You are not stating where s.DueDate comes from. It wont even compile.

In this SELECT the table is completely irrelevant

```
Select a.STID as STID,
@pdU As PastDueUnits,
@activeU As ActiveUnits,
@pdD As PastDueDollars,
@projRent As ProjRent,
@pdP As PastDuePerc,
@foU As FalloutUnits,
@foD As FalloutDollars,
@foP As FalloutPerc

FROM Agreemnt a INNER JOIN CashProj on a.STID = CashProj.STID JOIN Invntry i ON a.STID = i.STID JOIN AgreHist h On i.InvID = h.InvID And i.STID = h.STID INNER JOIN Agreemnt a On a.STID = h.STID AND a.AgreeID = h.AgreeID AND a.AStatID = h.AStatID 
WHERE a.RentToRent = 0 AND i.InvStatID = 11 AND i.DisposalDate IS NULL AND a.AStatID = 1 AND a.DueDate < DateAdd(d, @runDate, GetDate())
GROUP BY a.STID
ORDER BY a.STID
```

This is an example to how you should set the values before you try to do calculations with the variables.

```
    DECLARE @dayNum INT;
SET @dayNum = datepart(dw, getdate());

Select Invntry.STID,
  @foU = COUNT(Invntry.StockNumber) 
From Invntry
  Inner Join AgreHist On Invntry.InvID = AgreHist.InvID And
    Invntry.STID = AgreHist.STID
  Inner Join Agreemnt On Agreemnt.STID = AgreHist.STID And Agreemnt.AgreeID =
    AgreHist.AgreeID And Agreemnt.AStatID = AgreHist.AStatID
Where Invntry.InvStatID = 11 And Invntry.DisposalDate Is Null And
  Agreemnt.AStatID = 1 And Agreemnt.DueDate < DateAdd(d, Case @dayNum When '1' Then -2 When '2' Then 1 When '3' Then 1 When '4' Then 1
    When '5' Then 1 When '6' Then 0 When '7' Then -1 End, GetDate()) And Agreemnt.RentToRent = 0
Group By Invntry.STID
```

Comment: Excuse my lack of knowledge... if I went this way, with the variable within the select statement, then I would have to run multiple queries? How would I stack them?

Comment: To stack them you follow the way @dotjoe  suggests. You select first then assign in the last SELECT of his exmaple.

Comment: After re-reading @dotjoe suggestion, I think I understand. What I still can't wrap my mind around is how to calculate the two final percentages from these calculations and output the data.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was a lack of knowledge and understanding of SQL, which I'm improving on.  Here is what I ended up with that gave me the result I desired, whether the most efficient or not.

```
 SET DATEFIRST 1;
 DECLARE @Today date = dbo.getdateparam(92,999);
 DECLARE @TodayNum int = DATEPART(dw, @Today);
 DECLARE @Saturday date = DATEADD(DAY, (6-@TodayNum)%7, @Today);
 DECLARE @PrevSat date = DATEADD(DAY, -7, @Saturday);

 Select store.STID As Store,
   Proj.ProjRent As Projected,
   PDRent.PastDueDollars As PDRent,
   UOR.Units As UOR,
   PDUnits.UnitsPD As PDUnits,
   (PDRent.PastDueDollars / Proj.ProjRent) * 100 As FloatPerc,
   (Cast(PDUnits.UnitsPD As Decimal) / Cast(UOR.Units As Decimal)) * 100 As UnitPerc,
   Cast(Round((((PDRent.PastDueDollars / Proj.ProjRent) * 100) + ((Cast(PDUnits.UnitsPD As Decimal(18,4)) / Cast(UOR.Units As Decimal(18,4))) * 100)) / 2, 2) As Decimal(18,2)) As PDPerc,
   Reds.RedsPD As PDReds,
   Round(Cast(Reds.RedsPD As Float) / Cast(UOR.Units As Float) * 100,2) As RedsPerc
 From 
  -- Stores
 (Select Distinct Stores.STID,
     Stores.StoreName,
     Stores.EMail,
     Stores.ManagersName
   From Stores
   Where Stores.STID Not In (7, 999)) As store

  -- Projected Rent
   Left Join (Select CashProj.STID,
     Sum(CashProj.ProjectedRental) As ProjRent
   From CashProj
   Where CashProj.ProjectionDate Between DateAdd(mm, DateDiff(mm, 0, @Today),0) And DateAdd(mm, DateDiff(mm, 0, @Today) + 1, 0)
   Group By CashProj.STID) As Proj On store.STID = Proj.STID

  -- Past Due Float
   Left Join (Select Agreemnt.STID As STID,
     Sum(DateDiff(d, Agreemnt.DueDate, (Case DatePart(dw, @Today) When '1' Then DateAdd(DAY, -7, DateAdd(DAY, (6 - DatePart(dw, @Today)) % 7, @Today)) When '6' Then @Today
       Else DateAdd(DAY, (6 - DatePart(dw, @Today)) % 7, @Today) End)) * Round(Agreemnt.WeeklyRate / 7, 2)) As PastDueDollars,
     DatePart(dw, @Today) As TodayNum,
     DateAdd(DAY, -7, DateAdd(DAY, (6 - DatePart(dw, @Today)) % 7,
@Today)) As PrevSat,
     DateAdd(DAY, (6 - DatePart(dw, @Today)) % 7, @Today) As Saturday
   From Agreemnt
   Where Agreemnt.AStatID = 1 And Agreemnt.DueDate < (Case DatePart(dw, @Today) When '1' Then DateAdd(DAY, -7, DateAdd(DAY, (6 - DatePart(dw, @Today)) % 7, @Today)) When '6' Then @Today Else DateAdd(DAY, (6 - DatePart(dw, @Today)) % 7, @Today) End) And Agreemnt.RentToRent = 0
   Group By Agreemnt.STID) As PDRent On store.STID = PDRent.STID

  -- Units On Rent
   Left Join (Select Invntry.STID,
     Cast(Count(Invntry.StockNumber) As Int) As Units
   From Invntry
     Inner Join AgreHist On Invntry.InvID = AgreHist.InvID And
       Invntry.STID = AgreHist.STID
     Inner Join Agreemnt On Agreemnt.STID = AgreHist.STID And
       Agreemnt.AgreeID = AgreHist.AgreeID And Agreemnt.AStatID =
       AgreHist.AStatID
   Where Invntry.InvStatID = 11 And Invntry.DisposalDate Is Null And Agreemnt.AStatID = 1
   Group By Invntry.STID) As UOR On store.STID = UOR.STID

  -- Past Due Units
   Left Join (Select Invntry.STID,
     Cast(Count(Invntry.StockNumber) As Int) As UnitsPD
   From Invntry
     Inner Join AgreHist On Invntry.InvID = AgreHist.InvID And
       Invntry.STID = AgreHist.STID
     Inner Join Agreemnt On Agreemnt.STID = AgreHist.STID And
       Agreemnt.AgreeID = AgreHist.AgreeID And AgreHist.AStatID =
       Agreemnt.AStatID
   Where Invntry.InvStatID = 11 And Invntry.DisposalDate Is Null And
     Agreemnt.AStatID = 1 And Agreemnt.DueDate < (Case @TodayNum When '1' Then @PrevSat When '6' Then @Today Else @Saturday End) And Agreemnt.RentToRent = 0
   Group By Invntry.STID) As PDUnits On store.STID = PDUnits.STID

  -- Reds
   Left Join (Select Invntry.STID,
     Count(Invntry.StockNumber) As RedsPD
   From Invntry
     Inner Join AgreHist On Invntry.InvID = AgreHist.InvID And Invntry.STID = AgreHist.STID
     Inner Join Agreemnt On Agreemnt.STID = AgreHist.STID And Agreemnt.AgreeID = AgreHist.AgreeID And Agreemnt.AStatID = AgreHist.AStatID
   Where Invntry.InvStatID = 11 And Invntry.DisposalDate Is Null And Agreemnt.AStatID = 1 And Agreemnt.DueDate < DateAdd(day, -15, Case Cast(DatePart(dw, @Today) As Int) When '1' Then Cast(DateAdd(DAY, -7, DateAdd(DAY, (6 - DatePart(dw, @Today)) % 7, @Today)) As Date) When '6' Then Cast(@Today As Date) Else Cast(DateAdd(DAY, (6 - DatePart(dw, @Today)) % 7, @Today) As Date) End) And Agreemnt.RentToRent = 0
   Group By Invntry.STID) As Reds On store.STID = Reds.STID
 Order By Store
```